# Unable to add a correct undo/redo operation for move/scale/rotate using arcgis

Tags: javascript, arcgis, undo-redo

I have the following code by which I am reading when a graphic is being moved (scaling and rotation use similar code).

```
//Obtaining the graphic before it is moved
moveToolbar.on("graphic-move-start", function (evt) {
oldGraphicMove = evt.graphic;
});

//Updating the graphic on move end
moveToolbar.on("graphic-move-stop", function (evt) {

  //Creating the operation to add to the undomanager
  var operation = new Update({
  featureLayer: evt.graphic._graphicsLayer, //The layer that will contain the modified graphic
  preUpdatedGraphics: [oldGraphicMove], //The graphic before the changes are created
  postUpdatedGraphics: [evt.graphic] //The graphic after the changes are made
});

//Adding the undo/redo operation
undoManager.add(operation);
//Updating the graphic
evt.graphic._graphicsLayer.applyEdits(null, [evt.graphic], null);
```

});

For some reason the old graphic before is always staying equal to the new graphic after so when the operation is added there is nothing to undo/redo as the graphic is marked as equal before and after.

I have no idea what I might be doing wrong, any clues about this?

Comment: Could you share some sample at JSBIN? It would be easier to help. I guess moveToolbar is a graphic layer but more information would be nice. By the way you are using evt out of the scope, don't you?. BTW: I guess you know [this sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=graphics_undoredo), right?

Comment: JSBIN? moveToolbar is a toolbar from esri, it impacts the layer on the map depending on the operations assigned to the toolbar and the layer assigned :  moveToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Edit.MOVE | esri.toolbars.Edit.SCALE | esri.toolbars.Edit.ROTATE, tempMoveLayer.graphics[graphicNum])
Also yeah I know about it, and for Adding, Editing and Deleting graphics I have no issues as well as for undoing and redoing vertex movements. The issue is with move, scale and rotate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the oldGraphicMove variable on the start of editing was being overwritten by the evt.graphic from the editing end. This was resolved by creating a new graphic with the specifications of the graphic before it was edited rather than assigning the graphic directly to the variable :

```
//Obtaining the graphic before it is scaled
moveToolbar.on("scale-first-move", function (evt) {
     oldGraphicScale = new esri.Graphic(evt.graphic.geometry,evt.graphic.symbol,evt.graphic.attributes);
                                                    });

//Updating the graphic on scale end
moveToolbar.on("scale-stop", function (evt) {

    newGraphicScale = new esri.Graphic(evt.graphic.geometry, evt.graphic.symbol, evt.graphic.attributes);

   //Creating the operation to add to the undomanager
   var operation = new Update({
         featureLayer: evt.graphic._graphicsLayer, //The layer that will contain the modified graphic  
         preUpdatedGraphics: [oldGraphicScale], //The graphic before the changes are created
         postUpdatedGraphics: [newGraphicScale] //The graphic after the changes are made
                                                        });

//Adding the undo/redo operation
undoManager.add(operation);

//Updating the graphic
evt.graphic._graphicsLayer.applyEdits(null, [evt.graphic], null);
                                                    });
```

There are still a few issues with undoing/redoing movement, however this method works for undoing/redoing scale and rotation.